# Getting key code from pressing keyboards special keys (ex. macro keys on Razer Blackwidow Chroma)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, keyboard-input

I am new to c++ and developing windows desktop application.
I want to catch the event when user presses a non-standard key on keyboard, ex. macro key on Razer Blackwidow Chroma.

Currently I'm successfully catching all the other standard keys:

```
WM_KEYDOWN: 0x41
WM_CHAR: a
INPUT HAPPENED, I want this triggered when pressing macro keys! 
WM_KEYUP: 0x41
```

.. but pressing `M1`-`M5` on this keyboard does not trigger the event.

I also added the keyboard to be listened as `RAWINPUTDEVICE`, but still nothing.

Code fragment from message `WndProc`:

```
..
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        OutputDebugStringW(L"Hello World initialization...\n");

        RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[1];
        Rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
        Rid[0].usUsage = 0x06;
        Rid[0].dwFlags = 0;
        Rid[0].hwndTarget = 0;

        if (RegisterRawInputDevices(Rid, 1, sizeof(Rid[0])) == FALSE) {
            //registration failed. Call GetLastError for the cause of the error
            OutputDebugStringW(L"Error");
        }

        break;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        swprintf_s(msg, L"WM_KEYDOWN: 0x%x\n", wParam);
        OutputDebugString(msg);
        break;

    case WM_KEYUP:
        swprintf_s(msg, L"WM_KEYUP: 0x%x\n", wParam);
        OutputDebugString(msg);
        break;

    case WM_CHAR:
        swprintf_s(msg, L"WM_CHAR: %c\n", (wchar_t)wParam);
        OutputDebugString(msg);
        break;
    case WM_INPUT:
        OutputDebugStringW(L"INPUT HAPPENED, I want this triggered when pressing macro keys! \n");
        break;
..
```

Do I need to look at keyboard not as a `RAWINPUTDEVICE`, but as a USB device, can I get the signal then?
Or am I wrong in assuming that keyboard, by default, is sending a key code signal to OS regardless of driver presence on the OS?

If you wanna play around and test this on your keyboard, here's the whole file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// Global variables

// The main window class name.
static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("DesktopApp");

// The string that appears in the application's title bar.
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Windows Desktop Hello World Application");

HINSTANCE hInst;

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow
)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    // Store instance handle in our global variable
    hInst = hInstance;

    // The parameters to CreateWindow explained:
    // szWindowClass: the name of the application
    // szTitle: the text that appears in the title bar
    // WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of window to create
    // CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position (x, y)
    // 500, 100: initial size (width, length)
    // NULL: the parent of this window
    // NULL: this application does not have a menu bar
    // hInstance: the first parameter from WinMain
    // NULL: not used in this application
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 100,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    // The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
    // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
    // nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
    ShowWindow(hWnd,
        nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Main message loop:
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    TCHAR greeting[] = _T("Hello, Windows desktop!");
    wchar_t msg[255];

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        OutputDebugStringW(L"Hello World initialization...\n");

        RAWINPUTDEVICE Rid[1];
        Rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
        Rid[0].usUsage = 0x06;
        Rid[0].dwFlags = 0;
        Rid[0].hwndTarget = 0;

        if (RegisterRawInputDevices(Rid, 1, sizeof(Rid[0])) == FALSE) {
            //registration failed. Call GetLastError for the cause of the error
            OutputDebugStringW(L"Error");
        }

        break;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        swprintf_s(msg, L"WM_KEYDOWN: 0x%x\n", wParam);
        OutputDebugString(msg);
        break;

    case WM_KEYUP:
        swprintf_s(msg, L"WM_KEYUP: 0x%x\n", wParam);
        OutputDebugString(msg);
        break;

    case WM_CHAR:
        swprintf_s(msg, L"WM_CHAR: %c\n", (wchar_t)wParam);
        OutputDebugString(msg);
        break;
    case WM_INPUT:
        OutputDebugStringW(L"INPUT HAPPENED, I want this triggered when pressing macro keys! \n");
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        TextOut(hdc,5, 5,greeting, _tcslen(greeting));

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the Macro keys even send a keycode? They may just send combinations of other standard keycodes.

Comment: Well that's the pickle - how do I make sure?